# 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, ubuntu

Installed a LAMP stack, and now presented with this when I try and connect to my DB, my aim is to install SNIPE-IT, however I am somewhat new to the Linux environment.

Please take a look at my webmin log;

---

```
/etc/init.d/mysql[9744]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in

/etc/init.d/mysql[9744]: #007mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

/etc/init.d/mysql[9744]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'

/etc/init.d/mysql[9744]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
/etc/init.d/mysql[9744]: 

mysql[9432]:    ...fail!

systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.

systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.

systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Update - Cannot uninstall mysql either to try a fresh install.

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mysql-client-5.7 : Depends: mysql-client-core-5.7 but it is not going to be installed

mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)."

Comment: Make sure that the configuration is set up to communicate via IP address i.e. localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Please update your Q with this information then delete the comment. Qs should be standalone and clearly documented with all relevant information. So please delete your comment as it just slows readers down and invites further "conversation" in comments that should be part of your Q. and Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Change the config in your my.cnf file